# Align single list item in center CSS

Tags: html, css, reactjs, flexbox

I am creating a navigation bar in Reactjs with four elements. These items are a simple unordered list with some css using flexbox to align them horizontaly.

```
<ul>
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
    <li>Three</li>
    <li>Four</li>
<ul/>
```

What I want to achieve is: When a list item is selected, align the selected list item to center. I have added a professional picture for clarification. This change will later be animated for a smooth transition, like a carousel.

[image: The selected item appear in the center row]

Following is the css for `<ul>` tag.

```
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

What I've tried is to use the `align-self: center` on the one of the `<li>` items, but with no luck.

Does anyone have any experience with doing something similar? I am open for all types of solutions, even those that does not use flexbox.

Thank You!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do the list elements have a fixed with, and do you know how many items there are? If so, you can calculate the center of the list, the item offset, and add a CSS transform.

**Example:**

- You have a list of four items.
- Each item has width equal to 100px.
- The total width of the list is therefore 400px.
- The center point of the list is 200px from the left.
- The center point of item number two is 150px from the left. We therefore have to move the list 200px - 150px = 50px from the left.
- The center point of item number four is 350px from the left. We therefore have to move the list 200px - 350px = -150px from the left.

If your list is dynamic, both regarding to list length and item width, you can use [Element.getBoundingClientRect()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect) to find the elements' dimensions, and use the same calculations as above.

**Codepen:** https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vjJMVL

**HTML:**

```
<ul class="selected-2">
  <li>1</li>
  <li class="selected">2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
</ul>

<ul class="selected-4">
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li class="selected">4</li>
</ul>
```

**CSS:**

```
ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  list-style: none;
}

li {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: #eee;
  margin: 10px;
}

.selected {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.selected-2 {
  transform: translateX(50px)  
}

.selected-4 {
  transform: translateX(-150px)  
}
```

Comment: This looks great! Yes, the list if of fixed size and will never change. Just one question, do you know if I am able to animate the transition between selected items using `transition` property of css?

Comment: Yes, you can! I updated the codepen with a toggle in the upper left corner to demonstrate the transition effect: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vjJMVL

Answer (score 1):

Calculate the clicked `<MenuItem>` center by using [`Element.getBoundingClientRect()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect) to get it's `left`, and `width`, and pass it to the parent (`<Menu>`). In the parent use the `<ul>`s ref to get it's `left` and width with `Element.getBoundingClientRect()`. Calculate the `moveTo` state, and update the `<ul>`s style `transform: translateX()` accordingly:

```js
const { Component } = React;
const items = ['One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four'];

class MenuItem extends Component {
  clickHandler = (e) => {
    const { left, width } = e.target.getBoundingClientRect();
    const itemCenter = left + width / 2;
    this.props.updateCenter(itemCenter);
  }

  render() {
    const { children } = this.props;
    
    return (
      <li onClick={this.clickHandler}>{children}</li>
    );
  }
}

class Menu extends Component {
  state = {
    moveTo: 0
  };
  
  updateCenter = (itemCenter) => {
    const { left, width } = this.ul.getBoundingClientRect();
    
    //this.ul.style.transform = `translateX(${center}px)`;
    
    this.setState(() => ({
      moveTo: left + width / 2 - itemCenter
    }));
  };

  render() {
    const { items } = this.props;
    const { moveTo } = this.state;
    
    return (
      <nav>
        <ul ref={(ul) => this.ul = ul} style={{
          transform: `translateX(${moveTo}px)`
        }}>
        {
          items.map((text) => (
            <MenuItem key={text} 
              updateCenter={this.updateCenter}>
              {text}
            </MenuItem>
          ))
        }
        </ul>
      </nav>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Menu items={items} />,
  demo
);
```

```css
/** demo only - display the center **/
body::before {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  height: 100vh;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  content: '';
}

nav {
  overflow: hidden;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  justify-content: center;
  transition: transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275);
}

li {
  padding: 1em;
  border: 1px solid black;
  cursor: pointer;
}

ul li:not(:last-child) {
  margin: 0 1em 0 0;
}
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="demo"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since i don't fully get what you want, this is the best i could have came up with, applying absolute positioning to the selected one and have it overlap the others with z-index

```js
document.querySelectorAll('li').forEach(function(li){
 li.addEventListener('click',function(e){
  document.querySelectorAll('li').forEach(function(obj){
   obj.classList.remove('selected');
  });
  e.target.classList.add("selected");  
 });
});
```

```css
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    justify-content: center;
}


li{
    border:1px solid;
    padding:10px;
    cursor:pointer;
    position:relative;
    transition:all ease 1s;
    margin:0 20px;
}


.selected{
    transform:scale(2.1);
    background:white;
    box-shadow:0px 0px 55px black;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:5;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
    <li>Three</li>
    <li>Four</li>
</ul>
```